# STM32 HAL_UART Lora communication

Tags: c, arduino, uart, arduino-c++, lora

I have 2 LoRa modules. I want to use one of them as receiver and the other one as transmitter. I can do this with 2 Arduino Unos, but I want to use one STM32 board as transmitter and Arduino Uno board as receiver. I am using an Ebyte LoRa module, E32433T20D.

I set the receiver like this :

`{0x00, 0x01, 0x1A, 0x17, 0xC0} ;`

Here is my Arduino transmitter code.

```
#define PIN_SERIAL1_TX (0u)
#define PIN_SERIAL1_RX (1u)

#define M0 14
#define M1 15

void setup() {
  pinMode(M0, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(M1, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(M0, LOW);
  digitalWrite(M1, LOW);
  Serial1.begin(9600); // UART initialize I am using RP2040 with Arduino code
}

void loop() {
    Serial1.write((byte)0x00); // Receiver address
    Serial1.write(0x01);       // Receiver address                                                
    Serial1.write(0x17);       // Receiver channel = 0x17 = 23    (410M+23=433 MHz)
    Serial1.println("123");
    delay(500);
}
```

This code can transmit "123" without any problem. When I try this in C:

```
#include "main.h"
UART_HandleTypeDef huart1;
UART_HandleTypeDef huart2;

void SystemClock_Config(void);
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);
static void MX_USART2_UART_Init(void);  //debug
static void MX_USART1_UART_Init(void);  //Lora

/* USER CODE BEGIN 0 */
uint16_t readValue;
uint8_t charToTransmit[1];

/* USER CODE END 0 */

int main(void) {
  HAL_Init();
  SystemClock_Config();
  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_USART2_UART_Init();  //DEBUG
  MX_USART1_UART_Init();
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB,GPIO_PIN_5,0); //M0
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOC,GPIO_PIN_7,0); //M1
  HAL_Delay(100);
  uint8_t config[]=  {0x00,0x01,0x1A,0X17,0XC0};

  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  while (1) {
        charToTransmit[0] = 1 ;
        HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart1,config,sizeof(config),0);
        HAL_Delay(500);
        HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart1,charToTransmit,1,100);
        HAL_Delay(500);
    /* USER CODE END WHILE */

    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */
  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */
}

// There is HAL library initialization over here
```

This code is not transmitting or my receiver is not receiving, I don't know, but I can't see "1" on my receiver. Since I am a beginner in C, is my UART protocol wrong or something?

Here is my receiver program, I wrote it in the Arduino IDE too.

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#define PIN_SERIAL1_TX (0u)
#define PIN_SERIAL1_RX (1u)
#define M0 14
#define M1 15
char rc;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial1.begin(9600);
  pinMode(M0, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(M1, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(M0, LOW);
  digitalWrite(M1, LOW);
}

void loop() {
    while (Serial1.available()) {
      rc=Serial1.read();
      Serial.print(rc);   
    }
  }
```

Comment: I don't see anywhere in the STM32 code where the baud speed is inited. Is that taken care of somewhere else?

Comment: @dda I am using cubemx ide, I initialize it from peripheral side. I set it to 9600. I manage the get this code work, I used decimal instead of hex values.

Comment: and its add these line automatically.
```static void MX_USART1_UART_Init(void)
{
  huart1.Init.BaudRate = 9600; ```